# Laravel table::create sqlserver date conversion on sql server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, datetime, model, type-conversion

I aprettiate if somebody can help me.

In my db Table on SQL Server I have the created_at and updated_at fields as datetime type:

```
[created_at] [datetime] NULL,

[updated_at] [datetime] NULL,
```

In my controller, when I use the table::create($request), I receive the message:

> Converting an nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in a
>   value out of range.(SQL: insert into [table] ([name], [username],
>   [email], [password], [desclasse], [custnum], [custbill], [federalId],
>   [updated_at], [created_at])  values (username, loginname,
>   email@domain.com, hashbytes('MD5','*******'), USR, 2183, 2183,
>   01776432000151, 2018-07-17 12:41:24.349, 2018-07-17 12:41:24.349))

The problem is the dateformat: 2018-07-17 12:41:24.349. When I try to make this insert directtly in SQL Server, the only way accepted is 
insert into table .... values (...,convert(datetime, '2018-07-17 12:41:24.349',121,...)

How can I prepare the created_at and updated_at fields to produce an insert with this convert(datetime... in model or any other place in Laravel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your default system date format?  If you want to use this format, but your local system datetime format conflicts, the only way to force it would be to make it into an ODBC format ... which doesn't have the dashes in the date portion, e.g. `20180717 12:41:24.349`.

Comment: right, but, I do not handle those fields, Create puts them on their own. Where should I treat them? The only place I have mentioned them was in model:     protected $fillable = [
        'field', 'field', 'field', 'field','created_at','updated_at',
    ];

Answer (score 1):

I found it!
In model I have to put protected $dateFormat = 'd/m/y H:i:s'; 
and it works.

Thanks anyway.